# how to use hashcode?

Tags: java

Could someone please explain how hashcode works? I am new in android. 
All I want to do is to get the hashcode of my edittext
that the user has inputted.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText txtCode, txtID;
Button enter;

@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     txtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtid);
     txtCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtcode);
     enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


         enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String a = txtID.getText().toString();
             int b = a.hashCode();
            txtCode.setText(b);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `hashCode()` is not Android-specific.

Comment: What's not working with the code you have now? What error are you getting?

Comment: You should see the javadoc for `Object`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html -- the .equals()/.hashCode() contract is explained in full.

Comment: theres no error actually on my code but theres always fore close on my emulator when i click enter.

Comment: how can i get the hashcode of my edittext?

Comment: @Stephen good explain to you what a hash code, go back to the code, you have to convert the hash code on the String and then you can put it on EditText: textCode.setText(b + "");

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct.  That is how you get the hashcode of some text entered in a text box.

(Or at least, if there *is* a problem, it is not in that aspect of the code.)

Perhaps you misunderstand the meaning and purpose of `hashcode`.  This method (which is implemented by all Java reference types) returns an `int` that represents a simple 32-bit hash for the target object:

- It is not a cryptographic hash.  Crypto hashes are generated another way.  A hash needs many more than 32 bits before you could even consider it to be "strong".
- It is not unique.  Hashes are *never* unique.
- It is not even "probably unique".  If you try often enough you are liable to see collisions with hashes for strings. Indeed, since the hash is 32 bits long, you are *guaranteed* to have seen at least one collision after trying `2^32` different strings.  And the mathematics says that you are likely to get a collision *much sooner than that*.

---

> There's no error actually on my code but there's always force close on my emulator when i click enter.

Use `logcat` to look for what is causing that "force close".  There is likely to be an entry with a stacktrace for the exception that is the immediate cause.  If you have trouble figuring out what the stacktrace means, add it to your Question ...